# unable to access this object in directive angular4

Tags: javascript, angular

I am creating HTMLImageElement in the angular directive.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, "src", this.onePxlImgPlaceHolder);

    // create HTML image element to load image in the background
    this.dynamicImg = new Image();
    // register the function that will be called on image load
    this.dynamicImg.onload = function () {
        this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, "src", this.dynamicImg.src);
    };

    this.dynamicImg.src = this.originalImgSrc;
}
```

Inside the `ngAfterViewInit`, `this` object is available but inside the function that is registered with `onload` is not available, so I cannot access `renderer` and `el`. Inside `onload` function, `this` object refers to the element itself.

I have even tried

```
this.dynamicImg.onload = function () {
            this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, "src", this.dynamicImg.src);
    }.bind(this);
```

not working!! What is the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to keep the scope:

```
this.dynamicImg.onload = () => {
  this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, "src", this.dynamicImg.src);
};
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch) answer provides an in-depth explanation of the differences between arrow and normal functions in Javascript, including how they handle `this`